# Managing daemons with emacs

Tags: terminal-emacs

Every morning I have the tedious task of staring a dozen or more service on my macOS.

During the day I might want to stop/kill a few of them

Some services error out on startup. I would like to inspect the stdout/stderr.

Sometimes I want to tail the service stdout/stderr.

It would also be cool to be able to freeze/suspend all services,
  for example to allow sufficient cpu for a live video streaming session.

Can emacs help me with this?

Some of the services I start daily:

```
neo4j start
node server.js
bundle exec rails server -p 3000
bundle exec rails server -p 3001
memcached -d
elasticsearch -D
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin/pg_ctl start -D '/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package might help: https://github.com/rejeep/prodigy.el

An alternative would be defining systemd user services and monitor them with something like https://github.com/lompik/helm-systemd